# Display objects with specific string value in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

If I want to display all the objects, I use the code below. But if I only want to display the objects where the value for the key "Favorite" = "Yes", then what? Example of this would be great.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];    

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                    pathForResource:@"Objects" ofType:@"plist"];

sortedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [sortedObjects count];
}
```

Ps. The Property List is an array with dictionaries.

Comment: I don't think you've posted all of the code to display all of the elements - don't you need a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function to actually use the data from `sortedObjects` in your table?

Comment: @ajd Well..the cells are created and populated in cellForRowAtIndexPath. But the objects im using to populate the cell(s) if any, are defined in viewDidLoad. numberOfRowsInSection is counting the objects, so I think this is all the needed code for this question to be answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new array, lets call it filtered, that you create by filtering sortedObjects, and use that to populate the table.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.Favorite == %@", @"Yes"];
NSArray *filtered = [sortedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if([[sortedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Favorite"] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```